# Cloud-front backed with Nginx (which proxies to S3) randomly missing already cached items?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I wish to serve images from a **S3 bucket** with **Cloudfront** as CDN frontend, for that I tried the following:

> What I **wish to acheive** (**Attempt 2**)  -- (**Misses cloudfront cache randomly**)

I have the following setup to serve images: ( **Cloudfront** --> **Nginx** --> **S3** )
[image: Cloudfront -> Nginx -> S3]

<<<<<<<< Sample **S3** headers >>>>>>>>>>
[image: Attempt-2 S3 headers]

<<<<<<<< Sample **Nginx -> S3** headers (Added **Cache-Control**) >>>>>>>>>>
[image: Attempt-2 Nginx->S3 headers]

<<<<<<<< Sample **Cloudfront -> Nginx -> S3** headers >>>>>>>>>>
[image: Attempt-2 Cloudfront->Nginx->S3 headers]

> What I am **currently working** with (**Attempt 1**) -- (**Hits cloudfront as expected everytime**)

[image: Cloudfront -> S3]

**Cloudfront Settings**:

- Respects `GET` params to support urls like (http://cdn.example.com/abc.jpg?v=1)
- Cache `TTL` set to **157680000** ( Fallback for ***Cache-Control*** )

What am I screwing up in **Attemp-2** with my headers ? ( **Cloudfront missing randomly** )

Url(http://cdn.example.com/abc.jpg) & Url(http://cdn.example.com/abc.jpg?v=1) both will have same `ETag`, is that fine ?

**Update**

**#AWS** followed up on **forums.aws.amazon.com**, still waiting for a reply:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=144286&tstart=0#

**Update2**

- Recent hit/miss behavioral change from cloudfront without changing anything.
- Earlier the hits/misses were random with no fix pattern
- Now, (with no change on my end) I am getting all hits 1 day and all misses the next day.
- This suggests that its 24 hour cache but TTL and cache headers suggest 5 year cache expiry.
- This is again weird and without any explanations.

Hey, **AWS** can you see this ???

Comment: To be clear, you are saying that the Nginx version sometimes generates a Cloudfront hit, but does not always generate a cloudfront hit... correct?  Does it hit more often than it misses, or does it miss more often than it hits?

Comment: Yes, (With Nginx in-between) it sometimes results in cloudfront hit and sometimes a miss. If I observe it over a small period of time (Hit it agian and again) - it hits and misses randomly. But when I observe it over a period of day, I mostly see misses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about `4 months` of repetitive to-n-fro with `amazon support` failed to resolve the issue.

All problems still persisting:

- The cache expires in about a day and misses after **24 hours**. ( My expiry is 1 year )
- All headers and **aws settings** verified by `amazon support` themselves
- Unfortunately, the company is still paying for this awful experience due to lockin.

[image]

```
------ After 24 hours ------
```

[image]

```
------ After 24 hours ------
```

[image]

```
------ After 24 hours ------
```

[image]

```
-------- And so on.. -------
```

Concluding, The problem still stands **unresolved** and **amazon support** seems to have given up. This is quiet a strange experience since `aws` is something we generally take for granted.

:(

Comment: have you tried serving assets directly from Nginx as a caching proxy from S3 without any CloudFront?

Comment: Yes, I did that but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the 2 IPs you listed in AWS forum when you run dig resolver-identity.cloudfront.net:

```
74.125.190.17 is from Google in CA, USA   
67.215.80.11 is from OpenDNS from Singapore
```

Are you using OpenDNS or Google DNS? If you are, can you try to disable them and see if CloudFront will work properly from then on?

There is an article here talking about the disadvantage when you using OpenDNS/Google DNS with CDN, which may be helpful. http://apcmag.com/why-using-google-dns-opendns-is-a-bad-idea.htm

Comment: Should we expect our users to do what you are suggesting ?
Whatever impact any DNS server is creating should be taken care by `Cloudfront`. I suppose this is why `CDN` are costly because its hard to do. Will you ask your customers to do what you are suggesting ?

Comment: Also, the other cloudfront backed directly with S3 works just fine on the same network and DNS resolver. How is that possible ?

Comment: By looking at your location, it appears you are from India. Checking OpenDNS's closest location, its either in Singapore, or somewhere in Europe. To CloudFront, it can only see the request coming from Singapore, or EU, or anywhere the DNS redirect from, there is no way for CloudFront to help you/take care here. To put it shortly, when you try to use different products, there will always be limitations and conditions. I believe this is not unique to CloudFront but for most of the CDN products.

Comment: For your second Q, to be honest I am not sure why, but I have a bit suspicion that the same result may happen as your try with the nginx proxy in the middle. If I were you, what I will do is set up a cron job running every half a minute for like an hour or so, to execute dig resolver-identity.cloudfront.net. Compare the result to see if it is indeed the cause of DNS. Again, I'm not certain this is the cause, that's why I suggest you to verify it first.

Comment: How is my other Cloudfront backed with S3 directly working just fine, I am using both from this very same location India. Please suggest the difference from the point of view of Cloudfront ?

Comment: I have a cron running to verify that `Cloudfront without Nginx` is hitting everytime (flawlessly) and `Cloudfront with Nginx` is missing randomly. Tested both on 2 different ISP providers (Same results).

Comment: Can you compare the dig resolver-identity.cloudfront.net A record in your both two tests? What IPs are resolved? Who are they belonging to? Where are they?

Comment: As shown in `aws forums` `dig resolver-identity.cloudfront.net` is resolving to different DNS addresses from the very same machine where I am conducting my tests. So, with the changing resolver `1 cloudfront` instance is working where as other is not. I doubt `DNS resolution` is causing this.

Comment: Actually this is the weird thing, dig command has nothing to do with your setup, with or without nginx. It's just a normal unix request, as a result, I'd double check why the same dig returns different results.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with any setup. Whatever its yielding (2 different IP) is same for both `cloudfront` instances out of which 1 is functioning as expected and the other isn't. :(

Comment: Please delete this answer, since it solves nothing. Its same as what's stated in aws forum.